# Formatting Email Umlaut and Linebreaks

Tags: php, email, encoding

I am just working on a mail function and have problem with formatting it.
I want to send the mail as HTML. The newlines shall be converted to linebreaks. Currently I am using these functions

```
$mail_filtered    = nl2br($mail_filtered);
$mail_filtered    = htmlspecialchars($mail_filtered);
```

The umlauts are shown correctly, if I use this function, but the linebreaks are shown as `<br/>` tags in the mail.
The mail header looks like this:

```
"Content-Type: text/html", "Charset=utf-8"
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) to add HTML line breaks to the “physical” line break sequences and apply [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) afterwards, you’re also converting the added `<br />` into `&lt;br /&gt;` that is then displayed as `<br />`:

```
$str = "foo\nbar>baz";
var_dump(nl2br($str) === "foo<br />\nbar>baz");  // bool(true)
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(nl2br($str)) === "foo&lt;br /&gt;\nbar&gt;baz");  // bool(true)
```

Do it the other way round, first use `htmlspecialchars` and than `nl2br`:

```
var_dump(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str)) === "foo<br />\nbar&gt;baz");  // bool(true)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Bt another Problem occured: I also have a Link in the email. It is shown like in the source code and as html Link. What could be the issue, here?

Comment: @Laura: `htmlspecialchars` replaces *every* `<`, `>`, `&` and `"` by its corresponding entity character reference.

Comment: And what do I have to do, that the Links are handled correctly?

Comment: @Laura: Well, why do you use `htmlspecialchars` anyway?

Comment: What would be a better solution?

Comment: @Laura: That depends on what you’re intending to achieve?

Comment: I want to send a html mail,whch shows Umlauts and Hyperlinks correctly, and where new Lines (Mail template come from the database) are converted to Linebreaks.

Comment: @Laura: If your data is encoded properly in UTF-8, you don’t need any conversion. In fact, `htmlspecialchars` does replace only the mentioned characters `&`, `<`, `>`, and `"`. It’s not like `htmlentities` that does also replace any character where there exists a named entity.